# What is the best way to upload files from VSCode to NetSuite?

Tags: visual-studio-code, netsuite

I would like to upload scripts directly from VSCode to NetSuite and vice versa to download it.

Which tool do you recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: See this, it works quite well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9wrP5GrFTU

Comment: Hi, Simon! I'm facing an issue with the GULP version. On the video he used the 0.1.0 version, and I have de 2.0.0 . Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Not VSCode specific but if you have to roll your own here is a public [Grunt Task](https://github.com/BKnights/grunt-netsuite) that can be used as the basis.